# How to make foreign key from Membership's users table to custom table in code first approach in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, membership-provider

I am creating a `MVC 4 application` in Code First approach and using `DefaultMembershipProvider` and `DefaultRoleProvider`, but I am  getting a problem in making foreign key of membership's users table to my custom table, which stores some additional information of users. Please provide me a way how can I do this.

Please suggest.

Comment: What problem you are getting please describe it. Show your table class definition.

Answer (score 0):

here's one way:

you create your tables using Code First entities.  Then you go to your database schema, right click the schema, select "Relationships" and manually create the relationship to the membership table in sql server.  You'll have to make sure that the membership table has been created in your database first.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option of using SimpleMembershipProvider?

If you do, this post http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model 
has a simple explanation of how to integrate the membership tables with your EF.
But I'm not sure you need a complete integration with EF, so go through some SimpleMembershipProvider tutorials to see if it covers your requirements. 
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/security/16-adding-security-and-membership

If not I assume you'll need to model all the DefaultMembershipProvider tables in your EF model and add the relationship there.